# The debugger stops at a breakpoint only once

Tags: debugging

I'm trying to debug [`eskk.vim`](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim). It has a `asym_filter` function. The function is invoked on each keypress when in a certain mode. The mode is entered by pressing `C-j` in Insert mode.

So, I set a breakpoint [at the beginning](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L382) (`:breakadd here`), enter Insert mode (`a`), press `C-j`, the debugger appears, I press `c<Enter>`, then I'm back in my buffer. From this point on no matter what I do, it doesn't stop at the breakpoint. Although I know it's set, and that that function gets executed. Am I missing something? Is the function in any way special?

**UPD** I noticed that it stops at a different place:

where I [set](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L2051) a breakpoint (line 2051) -> where it [stops](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L2167) (line 2167) 
[set](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L2078) (line 2078) -> [stops](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L2167) (line 2167) 
[line 382](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L382) -> [line 489](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L489) 
[expectations](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L408) (line 408) -> [real life](https://github.com/tyru/eskk.vim/blob/8e3f82a838452b44062c567dd8aad5f613931ec2/autoload/eskk.vim#L489) (line 489)

But still not sure if it stops more than once. I've gathered that info by restarting `vim`. `nvim` to be precise.

Comment: If the debugger appears, you may be running the « continue » command, which could affect what you’re seeing.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I understand that it doesn't redraw the screen while I'm stepping through code. But after I run `c`, the script finishes, and the screen redraws. More importantly, I've just found out that for some reason it stops at a different place, see the updated question.

Comment: Continue restarts execution and doesn't stop until another breakpoint is hit or execution ends. I don't see any mention of `next` or `step`. Have you used those? They both run one command before returning to the debugger. (The difference is the former steps over function calls and the latter steps into them). Might be easier to get your bearings versus `continue`.

Comment: @BLayer First, it stops at different places, as you can see from my question. That might be the reason it stops only once. Second, I didn't use `next` or `step` then, because I just wanted to confirm that it works as expected, stops after every keystroke.

Comment: @x-yuri The page was opened before the part beginning with "UPD" (update?) and didn't auto-refresh for some reason, i.e. I was missing some data points. Either way, it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the explanation, but I have a workaround. tpope's [`scriptease`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plugin has a `Breakadd here` analogue, which works as expected. But before that you've got to `:Runtime %`. The reason is explained [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease/issues/49).

Which makes me think that `vim` failing to set breakpoints properly has something to do with the script being supposed to be autoloaded.